# azure repo child branch is not triggering release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I am running a (Azure Repo)master branch through azure devops pipeline which is running fine.

I want to create child branch (Azure Repo) of the master branch(Azure Repo). Now, I want to deploy the child branch through the pipeline. The child branch create a new azure-pipeline.yaml file which is not triggering the release pipeline. Could you please be kind to give me the solution? how can I run pipeline for the child branch and what are the configurations are required?

Comment: Post your YAML.

Answer (score -1):

When configuring your release pipeline, enable the continuous deployment trigger and add both of the master branch and child branch. Then, every time a new build is finished on master or child branch, new release will be created and start the deployment.

[image]

Comment: The question is about YAML pipelines. You are including irrelevant screenshots from classic pipelines.